How can a request be started with Leaflet Routing Machine with one waypoint?
If a round trip is compiled with the Leaflet Routing Machine and lrm-openroutservice, this is not fired as the Leaflet Routing Machine requires a start and an end point => two waypoint.
openrouteservice.org can find a route with the round-trip attribute.
Only one waypoint may be specified as the end point is the starting point.
The lenght attribute specifies the approximate length of the route. OSR then searches for a route. If seed is also specified, the route for each sed setting between 1 ... 50 is chosen randomly... A perfect tool for hikes or bike tours etc... OSR API Spec.
var router = L.Routing.control({
            waypoints: [
                L.latLng(48.12, 8.22)
            ],
            router: new L.Routing.OpenRouteService(apikey, {
                "timeout": 45 * 1000,
                "format": "json",
                "host": "https://api.openrouteservice.org",
                "service": "directions",
                "api_version": "v2",
                "profile": "driving-car",
                "routingQueryParams": {
                    "options": {
                        "round_trip": {
                            "length": 10000,
                            "points": 3,
                        }
                    }
                }
            }),
        }).addTo(map);

What can I do to ensure that the Leaflet Routing Machine also starts a request with one waypoint for the round-trip attribute?
Round Trip Example

This is not clear. If you want to get round trip with only one point and no other data, there is almost infinite number of round trips, unless you are on a road segment that is isolated.

Yes, openrouteservice.org can find a route with the round-trip attribute. only one waypoint may be specified as the end point is the starting point. the lenght attribute specifies the approximate length of the route.
OSR then searches for a route. If seed is also specified, the route for each sed setting between 1 ... 50 is chosen randomly... A perfect tool for hikes or bike tours etc...  OSR API Spec.

@TomazicM The length of the rout is the limiter and seed is the random for the rout.

Did you manage to make it work with two points? I didn't.

The OSR service 'round-trip' only works with one waypoint... I have not yet been able to get the leaflet routing machine to start a request with only one waypoint

I'm asking about two points. Did you manage to make lrm-openroutservice work with two points? I had no success.

@TomazicM Yes, lrm-openroutservice with two Waypoints and without round-trip attributes works fine

Can you post your working code?

The code is included in the question. Thats all.

I can't make it work event with two points. I'm getting errors.
